# Submitted a form via Jmeter script on Liferay DXP, not getting saved in DB(Postgres)

Tags: performance, jmeter, liferay, liferay-dxp

Submitted a form via Jmeter script on Liferay DXP,

after submit the values are not getting saved in Postgres DB

Note: Simple form without login 
authentication token (p_auth) is correlated for each and every request using 'regular expression extractor'.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have enough information to guess the exact reason so here are the most common:

1. You're simply not authenticated, make sure [to be logged in](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html#logging_in) prior attempting to submit a form. Also add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan - it automatically handles cookies and deals with cookie-based authentication.
2. Most probably your Liferay deployment uses [authentication token](https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Authentication+Token) (usually `p_auth`) so you will need to **correlate** it for each and every request, otherwise it will be rejected. See [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites) article for more information on the topic.

Get used to verifying the integrity of your test plan using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request and response details, most probably you will be able to figure out what went wrong from the webpage response.

Comment: - it is a guest page, hence login not required
- However HTTP cookie manager is added
- p_auth is handled through 'regular expression extractor'
- data was saved in liferay 6.2 but not getting saved for Liferay DXP